# How to check that url is file for download using chromium, selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, chromium

I am using chromium and selenium in NodeJS.

I have some links for test...

When I call `this.driver.get(url)` url is loaded correctly.

Problem is when url is path to some file, for example `www.example.com/file.zip`.
After open this link, file is downloaded and selenium freeze.

I dont know how to filter link like this. Or unfreeze selenium. Is there any way how to do this?

I can filter links with exntension `.zip`, but what about next file formtas?